# Are all Magisk Modules Open Source?

Tags: root-access, xposed-framework, magisk

I noticed the main place to download modules is here

https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo

some in the links section link the source which just loops back to the same page. So are all the modules hosted on github itself open source? as i see what looks like the contents of each module there.

I suppose some modules might be posted on XDA that aren't on github and i know not all Xposed modules on Xda or repo.xposed.info aren't open source.

Appreciate all help.

Comment: So everything hosted on https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo are open source definitely? i'm surprised since i'm used to having to hunt for open source root apps or xposed modules. It's up to the dev to decide to open source apps. Tho there's a lot of potential threats xposed modules or root apps can pose without been open source. I thought it was going to be the same game with Magisk modules as i'm sure these to would be able to pose same threats a malicious xposed module or root app can.

Comment: None specifically i'm no dev i don't no what source code looks like, https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/MIUI-10-Camera so all files abouve "README.md" are the open source code? or are all projects on github open source?

Comment: All projects in general on Github are open code but they can have a closed component that is a pro feature. I am yet to see that with Magisk

Comment: Upvoted for asking an interesting question

Answer (score 1):

Github does not equal open source. Because a Magisk module is on Github it does not mean it is open source

You can have both open and closed projects hosted on Github and Magisk is no exception as you can see from this [XDA post by Magisk developer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=68987141&postcount=7) (though instructions pertaining to Magisk are outdated)

There are projects hosted on Github with a portion of the code which is closed source and is offered as paid or pro version, for example code of
[FairEmail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.email) is available on Github but the pro version features are not open source. Though I am not aware of any such Magisk module with pro component

Though this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16933385/10193147) question is old, it gives pointers to better understand

Comment: Thanks. I used to equate Github with open source, at least the publically accessible repositories.

Comment: @Firelord : welcome. Me too, till I did some reading after seeing this question

Comment: @Firelord : Added a [SO] source and here is a [Quora discussion](https://www.quora.com/Why-must-projects-on-GitHub-be-open-sourced).

Answer (score 0):

I asked somewhere else. The response was.

If the Module has a LICENCE file listed in the github listing it's open source.

Magisk modules generally have their code publicly available (if it's not on GitHub you can just open the zip and read the code). There might be included binaries and apps that don't have the code available, of course.

Don't mistake publicly available code for open source. It's not the same thing... A Magisk module doesn't have to be open source for you to be able to see what it does.