# Do Magisk modules pose a privacy risk? How to overcome?

Tags: privacy, magisk

Further to this excellent answer here by Irfan Latif [How Magisk works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213167/131553) and considering that Magisk modules need not be open sourced ([Are all Magisk Modules Open Source?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203410/131553)), the question is

**Do they pose a privacy risk?**

(Risk as defined [here](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacyLua/blob/master/README.md))

I guess the answer is yes, for instance a battery performance module needs to know the device identifiers to tune the parameters (Lspeed d, FDE etc) but wanted to be sure

and if so, **what can one do to protect privacy** - outside of not using them :(

Note:Some modules like Lspeed create an app too but restricting app using XPrivacyLua seems pointless if the module itself is a risk.